# How to pass on best parameters (using GridSearchCV) from a pipeline to another pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I have a custom pipeline and I am using GridSearchCV from Sklearn to tune the parameters for the whole pipeline. I've the best parameter combination using the sklearn but I want to get the best parameter combination and pass to another pipeline.

Here's the pipeline,

```
p = Pipeline([
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            ('chargram', Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\w')),
                ('kbest', SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2)),
            ])),
            ('custom', Pipeline([
                ('features', CustomFeatures()),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                ('kbest', SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2)),
            ]))
        ],
        # weight components in FeatureUnion. Can be tuned
        transformer_weights={
            'chargram': 0.8,
            'custom': 0.8
        },
        n_jobs=-1
    )),

    # Classifier stage      
    (('clf', clf)),
])
```

So, in this pipeline, I also get the parameter combination for the classifier, but all I want to do is to get the parameters for featureunion step and pass this to the pipeline and use another set of classifier parameters to pass to the featureunion - both combined.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: While you have it why would you want to get it? You already have it.

Comment: I have multiple machine learning models to do and I don't want to tune the features again and again and use the same config that i test on the first classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can save parameters` values in variables like this:

```
transformer_list = [
    ('chargram', Pipeline([
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\w')),
        ('kbest', SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2)),
    ])),
    ('custom', Pipeline([
        ('features', CustomFeatures()),
        ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ('kbest', SelectPercentile(score_func=chi2)),
    ]))
]

transformer_weights = {
    'chargram': 0.8,
    'custom': 0.8
}

p = Pipeline([
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=transformer_list,
        # weight components in FeatureUnion. Can be tuned
        transformer_weights=transformer_weights,
        n_jobs=-1
    )),

    # Classifier stage
    (('clf', clf)),
])
```

P.S: I do not know If I understood you!

Comment: hey, thanks. I found a solution myself on the same lines, you can use the steps to get the params from the step. So for example, steps[0] in my code was what I was looking and I used that for model building for the other classifiers. Thank you for the help!